# How to join multiple rows (multiindex?) in pandas into one row OR How to extract parameters out of a request from an apache log (string)?

Tags: python, regex, apache, pandas

I am writing a script which parses request-parameters of an apache log file into a pandas table.

An example request is like this:

```
GET /v1/board?id=8504178&limit=1&to=8504177 HTTP/1.1
GET /v1/connections?from=850417&to=8504177 HTTP/1.1
GET /v1/location?query=850417
```

There are a lot of parameters and no fixed order. So I think the pandas method extract() will not work. 
That’s why I try to do it with extractall(). My first version of a regex expression and extracting with it is like this:

```
req_patt = ("(?P<request>GET) \/v1\/(?P<resource>connections|stationboard|locations)|"
        "from=(?P<from>.*?)&|"
        "to=(?P<to>\d*|\w*)(?P<to_del>&|\s)"
)


df_temp = df['fullrequest'].str.extractall( req_patt )
```

So that I get this Dataframe back:

```
actual output:
index  requests resources    from     to 
(0, 0) GET      connections  nan      nan
(0, 1) nan      nan          8504178  nan
(0, 2) nan      nan          nan      8504177
(1, 0) GET      stationboard nan      nan
(1, 1) nan      nan          nan      8504177
```

But in the end i would like to have something like this:

```
expected output: 
index  requests resources    from     to 
0      GET      connections  8504178  8504177
1      GET      stationboard nan      8504177
```

So my question in the end: 
How can i join these single rows to one row?

Comment: `(?P<request>GET(?=\s))|\/v1\/(?P<resource>[^?\s]*)|from=(?P<from>[^&\s]*)|to=(?P<to>[^&\s]*)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ndf = df.apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull).set_index('index')

ndf = ndf[~ndf.isnull().all(1)]
```

Output :

```
     requests     resources       from         to
index                                             
(0,0)      GET   connections  8504178.0  8504177.0
(0,1)      GET  stationboard        NaN  8504177.0
```

To get the index you can use `ndf.index = ndf.index.str[-2]`

```
     requests     resources       from         to
index                                             
0          GET   connections  8504178.0  8504177.0
1          GET  stationboard        NaN  8504177.0
```